# I can't connect the mysql container in docker with workbench in my machine

Tags: mysql, docker, workbench

I want to connect mysql container with workbench
I run mysql with this command

```
docker run --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root  -d mysql
```

I go to workbench interface  I add a new connection with this :

```
host : 127.0.0.1 
user: root
pwd :root 
port 3306
```

and I  test the connection.

The connection is failed.

what is the problem?

Comment: Does the container show any error logs? From what I see, the container seems to be started correctly.

Comment: Trying to reproduce this problem with given info was not possible. (I was able to start a connection to MYSQL on the just created docker instance)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that MySQL container is running in a separate network namespace which cannot be accessed via the host network. Here you are telling the container to bind to the loopback network interface of the container itself, not your local machine. When you try to connect to MySQL using Workbench on your local machine, it is not able to connect to the container because it is not listening on the host's network interface. You should use the IP address of the container itself instead of 127.0.0.1. Find the ip  address of the container using the docker inspect command.

You can find the ip address of the container through :

- Run the command docker ps to get the container ID of the MySQL container.
- Run the command docker inspect <container_id>.

This will give you ip address of the mysql container and then use that instead.

Comment: i do that and the ip adress is 172.17.0.2 but when I test the connection I have a other error : unable to connect to localhost

Comment: then check docker ps to see active containers and check mysql if not running start again. Else, do this mysql -h 172.17.0.2 -u root -p if it works  then the issue is with your workbench settings.